Getting an SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] error when publishing a laravel 11 project on cpanel shared hosting
Am trying to publish my project (laravel 11 inertia react) in cpanel shared hosting in bluehost but am stuck with this error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = 7GIjHM3xMS3armZMjGSemNKyAKEyuTtT9z4WfBda limit 1)

I have tried this already
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear

I even added artisan commands to my web.php hoping i can run it on the server but am getting a 404 response. this works on the previous laravel version
Route::post('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE clear-cache'; //Return anything
});

By the way I used laravel breeze on this app. I hope someone can point out what i am missing here.
thanks

Well your database credentials are not correct. Off the record: never connect a application to a database using the root user...
